# Get random values without replacement given a probability distribution

Tags: algorithm, math, random, language-agnostic

Given a probability distribution – a mapping of objects to their probability – I want an algorithm that selects random objects from the map and is without replacement (the probability distribution is updated per selection). However, the algorithm must have an O(1) space complexity and have high quality randomness. I tried searching for implementations, but none of them seemed to have both of these properties.

EDIT:

Probability without replacement:
You have a bag of objects, each object has a probability of being selected. Once you select an object, you remove it from the bag. All objects now a different probability of being selected.

With O(1) space complexity, we are not storing a list with objects repeated according to their probability of being selected. Instead, we are only storing a *probability distribution* and *iterating over a permutation* (but not storing that permutation).

Comment: Probability expressed as float or as an integer weight counting against the total (i.e. expressed as a rational ratio)?

Comment: @Adrian either is fine since they can both achieve the same result.

Comment: Are you OK with the destruction of the input object->probability map in the process?

Comment: What do you mean by "without replacement"?

Comment: Does the time complexity not matter to you? How do you define the "objects" without O(n) complexity? (That is possible for some kinds of sets of "objects" but not others, and that could affect the algorithm). Could there be an O(1) space complexity *for each object*? Most of all, why do you have these requirements? Your question seems vague as given.

Comment: Seems to me this is an X-Y problem. The proper, correct solution is to shuffle and store the permutation. The requirement forbids the storing of the permutation - the requirement is wrong unless you have a good reason why you can't store the permutation. Considering how much RAM even small microcontrollers have these days it's very hard to come up with a good reason. Remember, storing the permutation only requires you to store pointers to the objects (or indexes to the object's location in the original list)

Answer (score 0):

I would try variation of [Fisher-Yates-Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffle (in Durstenfeld implementation it is O(1))

Original:

```
for i from 0 to n − 1 do
  j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
  if j ≠ i
      a[i] ← a[j]
  a[j] ← source[i]
```

Modified to fulfill requirements:

```
for i from 0 to n − 1 do
  p ← probabilities(n-i)
  j ← random integer via probabilities(n-i) such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
  if j ≠ i
      a[i] ← a[j]
  a[j] ← source[i]
```

So at each step you would update probabilities and use them to sample index. After that it's just FYK shuffle.